# Quotient rule, one sign wrong

Tags: calculus

After using the quotient rule on

$$y=\frac{\cos x}{x}$$

I got

$$\frac{-x\sin x -\cos x}{x^2}.$$

However the answers says it should be

$$\frac{-x\sin x + \cos x}{x^2}.$$

So who's right?

Comment: It's always fun finding a mistake in a book. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28cos%28x%29%2Fx%29

Comment: So both forms are correct then?

Comment: @Paul Nope, you are correct, and the book answer is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paul, we meet again. I see you followed my previous answer and got the right answer. However, all your book did is a little bit of algebra:

$$\frac{-x\sin x -\cos x}{x^2} =\frac{(-1)(x\sin x +\cos x)}{x^2}= -\frac{x\sin x +\cos x}{x^2}$$

I'm assuming that's what it says in the book (and you wrote it wrong in your post). If not, then the book is wrong.

Comment: That's what I have just noticed, when I typed It in the mins should be like your last one. So everyone's right :)

Comment: Can't seem to edit that last comment, so to avoid confusion I should of said "minus" instead of "mins"

Answer (score 2):

$y=\dfrac{\cos x}{x}$

$y'=\dfrac{\cos x'\cdot x-\cos x\cdot x'}{x^2}=\dfrac{-x\sin x\color{red}-\cos x}{x^2}$

You are right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find it easier to rewrite in a way that allows use of the product rule.

$$y(x) = x^{-1}cos(x)$$ Now applying the power rule we have $$y'(x)=(-1)*x^{-2}cos(x)+x^{-1}(-sin(x))$$ which simplifies to $$y'(x)=-x^{-2}cos(x)-x^{-1}sin(x)$$ $$=\frac{-cos(x)}{x^{2}}-\frac{sin(x)}{x}$$ $$=\frac{-cos(x)}{x^{2}}-\frac{xsin(x)}{x^{2}}$$ $$=\frac{-cos(x)-xsin(x)}{x^{2}}$$ So as many users have already pointed out to you, you are indeed correct.

Comment: `\cos(x)` makes $\cos(x)$, which looks better than $cos(x)$.  Similarly for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!